# extending a method in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, class, methods

Hi all i currently have a method. and i would like to add an option to create a custom method once its been filled out when its called.

currently all my methods get call like

```html
let test = foo(var)
```

I would like to have the option to add this on top of the current method

```html
    let test = foo(var).bar('i want this added to current method')
```

I have no idea how to do this or even what this would be called.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a closure function to keep the value of an even after the inner function is returned

```js
 
 function foo(param1){

  var bar =  function (param2) {
   return param1 + param2;
  }
  return { bar };

}

var test = foo("Hello").bar("World!");  

console.log(test);
```

Comment: hey thank you i also found figured it out by wrapping the return statement in a class that has a method attached to it class bar{

 test: any;

constructor(other: any){
test = other;
}

 bar= () =>{
 console.log('adding to dictionary ')
}